# SMTP Pro doesn't work when selftest

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.2.2, smtp, email-translation

I just installed the SMTP Pro extension for sending emails by SMTP. I get the following errors:

Detected overwrite conflict:

```
CRM4Ecommerce_CRMCore_Model_Rewrite_Core_Email_Template
```

Please help and consider that I'm new to Magento. I couldn't find a solution on the internet. I run Magento 1.9.2

Comment: CRM4Ecommerce_CRMCore is this module belongs to smtp pro?

Comment: @saravanavelu No. This is another module that I installed

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this conflict by following 
go to this `class` file  `app/code/CLASSCODEPOOL/CRM4Ecommerce/CRMCore/Model/Rewrite/Core/Email/Template.php` and change its extending class to

```
Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email
```

so your class would be like this

```
class CRM4Ecommerce_CRMCore_Model_Rewrite_Core_Email_Template extends Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email{
    //your methods  .....
}
```

Comment: I did as you explained but now I get other messages!! SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Detected overwrite conflict: CRM4Ecommerce_CRMCore_Model_Rewrite_Core_Email_Template
Test email was sent successfully.
Could not test default template validity.
Exception message was: Invalid method CRM4Ecommerce_CRMCore_Model_Rewrite_Core_Email_Template::loadDefault(Array ( [0] => contacts_email_email_template [1] => en_US ) )...
Please check that you have templates in place for your emails. These are in app/locale, or custom defined in System > Transaction Emails.

Comment: so your solution is to replace (Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template) with (Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email) which I did but now I get the error message above.

Comment: you have to change your config.xml as well now you need to rewrite the SMTPpro extension model instead core email model

Comment: I don't think that I understood what you just said. Can you please explain? I'm new to this.

Comment: I just noticed when I edited the file you mentioned above and extended the class to Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email all transactional emails stopped working even if I try to preview a transactional email template. I restored the files and everything went back to normal. Still can't figure out how to fix this issue. Both authors and their websites don't respond so far.

Comment: provide config.xml of other extesntion

Comment: this is the config.xml for SMTP Pro: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/blob/master/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/etc/config.xml